# Python : Read constants directly in php file (no passing values)

Tags: python

there are plenty of examples around which show how to pass parameters while executing a python file and they work fine.

My question is about a slightly different subject.

Above the root of my server I have a dbinfo.inc.php configuration file with constants in use for my server:

```
<?php
define('DB_SERVER', '127.0.0.1');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
?>
```

I was wondering if there was a way to read those constants directly in Python.

Comment: Dump the constants into JSON, then read the JSON in python

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestion, I'll do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came to a solution thanks to tyteen4a03:

Created a file to grab and store in a array the constants I was looking for :

In Php:

```
<?php
include "dbinfo.inc.php";

$config = array(
    "DB_SERVER" => DB_SERVER,
    "DB_USERNAME" => DB_USERNAME, 
    "DB_PASSWORD" => DB_PASSWORD);

echo json_encode($config);
?>
```

In Python:

```
from subprocess import check_output
import json

config = check_output(['php', '../../inc/pythondbinfo.inc.php']).decode('utf-8')
config = json.loads(config)
```

So it's all fine.